# [Cannot read property 'setParams' of null]

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Am quite new to Lightning and trying to understand Events so far i have created two components making Parent Child component with help of Events. But getting the error

> "Action failed: c:MySampleChildCmp$controller$handleClick [Cannot read
>   property 'setParams' of null] Failing descriptor:
>   {c:MySampleChildCmp$controller$handleClick}"

Unable to identify the Error.

Here is  the code.

ChildToParentEvent.evt:-

```
<aura:event type="COMPONENT">
    <aura:attribute type="String" name="firstName"/>
    <aura:attribute type="String" name="lastName"/>
    <aura:attribute type="String" name="Phone"/>
</aura:event>
```

MySampleChildCmp:-

```
<aura:component>
    <!--<aura:attribute type="String" name="userData" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute type="String" name="firstName" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute type="String" name="lastname" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute name="Phone" type="Integer" default=""/>-->
    <aura:registerEvent name="ChildToParentEvnt" type="c:ChildToParent"/>
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Brand action" title="Brand action" onclick="{! c.handleClick }" />
</aura:component>
```

MySampleChildCmpController:-

```
({
    handleClick : function(component, event, helper) {
        alert('called Child component');        
        var evt = component.getEvent("c.ChildToParentEvnt");
        evt.setParams({'firstName' : SFDC,
                        'lastName' : Developer,
                        'Phone' : 9999999
                       });
            evt.fire();
        alert('called Event');
    }
})
```

MySampleParentCmp:-

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute type="String" name="userData" default="" />
    <aura:attribute type="String" name="firstName" default="ABC" />
    <aura:attribute type="String" name="lastName" default="DEF" />
    <aura:attribute type="Integer" name="Phone" default="" />
    <aura:attribute type="boolean" name="callChild" default="false" />
    <aura:handler name="ChildToParentEvnt" event="c:ChildToParent" action="{!c.handleClick}"/>
        <div>
           <c:MySampleChildCmp />
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>User Data from Event </h2>
        Name    : {!firstName} {!lastName}<br/><br/>
        Phone    : {!Phone}
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

MySampleParentController:-

```
({
    handleClick : function(component, event, helper) {
        alert('Called Parent');
        var lastName= event.getParam('lastName');
        var firstName= event.getParam('firstName');
        var Phone= event.getParam('Phone');
        component.set('v.lastName', lastName);
        component.set('v.firstName', firstName);
        component.set('v.phone', Phone);
    }
})
```

Comment: Kindly format the code while asking question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refer to this [example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_component_example.htm). You are facing issue because of line `component.getEvent("c.ChildToParentEvnt")`.

For getting view its `v.` and for getting controller method or apex method its `c.` BUT for getting event, you DO NOT have to use binder. Change the line to:

```
component.getEvent("ChildToParentEvnt")
```

Comment: Thanks peter, Now its working as expected